# App doesn't show up in the apps menu on Huawei Watch 2

Tags: android, wear-os, watch, huawei-mobile-services

I'm implementing an application in Android Studio. I'm running into a problem using my Huawei Watch 2. The app works fine, but I don't understand why it doesn't show up in the apps menu on the watch.

Going to Settings -> Apps and notifications -> Info app, I see my app.

What is happening, and how can I fix it?

Here is my Manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.prova._poc">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:targetApi="ice_cream_sandwich">

        <service
            android:name=".MyfirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />
        <!--
               Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
               app to run.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <!-- [START fcm_default_channel] -->
        <!-- [START fcm_default_channel] -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="gizmos"
                    android:scheme="example" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Splash">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="Splash" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I assume by "a menu list" you mean the app launcher on the watch... Can you post your watch app's manifest? Ideally the whole thing (if it's not too long), but at least the `<activity>` element for your app's main activity.

Comment: @String i've updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main `Activity`'s manifest entry is wrong. Specifically, for it to appear in the app launcher on any Android device, it needs an `<intent-filter>` element that looks like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I'm not sure why you have all the other stuff in there, but if you need it, create a second `<intent-filter>` element for it. You can have several intent-filters for a given `<activity>`, matching different intents - but the one for the launcher should **only** contain the `action` and `category` shown here.

More info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Having apps on your phone doesn't automatically install them on your watch as well. If you go to the Play Store app, then scroll down from the front screen, you'll see a heading marked Apps on your phone: these are all the apps on your phone that have Wear OS companion apps, which you can install by tapping on any of the buttons on the right.

Comment: I've a different problem. I'm using a stand alone smart watch, and  i'm implementing an app using android studio. I'm not considering play store app because my app isn't on app store.